# JScrollPane not resizing when added to JPanel

Tags: java, macos, swing, jscrollpane, look-and-feel

I cant get the `scrollPane` to resize correctly when added to the `scrollPanel`. I want the `scrollPane` to scale to the size of the `scrollPanel`. Any tips?

```
public class MTabbedPane_HomePanel extends JPanel {
    private JPanel scrollPanel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public MTabbedPane_HomePanel()
    {
        init();
        makePanel();
    }

    private void init() {
        scrollPanel             = new JPanel();
        scrollPane              = new JScrollPane(scrollPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    }

    private void makePanel() {
        IAppWidgetFactory.makeIAppScrollPane(scrollPane);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        scrollPane.setBorder(null);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the panel **inside** `JScrollPane` is empty and hence has no min, pref, or max size set (or rather, it has 0x0 size everywhere). Also it is better for the inner pane to implement `Scrollable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is correct, maybe

- try to disable UIDelegate from [IAppWidgetFactory.makeIAppScrollPane()](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/source/browse/trunk/source/com/explodingpixels/macwidgets/IAppWidgetFactory.java?r=364), if remains unchanged

then

- check how you added (if is used [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)) for MTabbedPane_HomePanel to the parent

Answer (score 1):

Call setPreferredSIze() for the panel.